# Is there a way to program an application that uses a database system and does not require install a database server on client machine

Tags: c#, c++, database, qt, qt5

**Notice:** this question general, It does not matter what is the programming language.  but my inquire about `c++ Qt`, `c#` languages.

I want programming an `windows application` that uses `database system`.
But I want choose a database system does not require install a database server on a client computer.   Just I want the client install the application, then he can use the application after installation and does not require install a database server.

I don't know what is the database appropriate to me ?
`mySql` , `msSql`, `sqlite`, `etc`.

Comment: Where the database files will be located? On server or client computer?
FYI you can also use Sql Server Compact Edition. It has setup up to 5mb. You must install it as a prerequisite on client.

Comment: @ Farhad Jabiyev: The database beside the application everywhere, `client computer`.

Comment: Check out related questions too - there are plenty of zero-install options.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite is a nice fast database to use in standalone applications. There's dozens of GUI's around to create the schema you want and interfaces for pretty much any language you would want (C/C++/Java/Python/Perl/C#). It's also cross platform and is suitable for Windows, Linux, Mac, Android, iOS and many other operating systems.

Here are some advantages for SQLite:

**• Speed :**

- In many cases at least 2-3 times faster than MySQL/PostgreSQL.
- No socket and/or TCP/IP overhead.

**• Functionality :**

- Sub-selects, Triggers, Transactions, Views.
- Up to 2TB of data storage.
- Small memory footprint.
- Self-contained: no external dependencies.
- Atomic commit and rollback protect data integrity.
- Easily movable database.

**• Security :**

- Each user has their own completely independent database(s).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `+1 for you` , I want to give you the best answer, but there is another one also has a good answer Mr:`Aaron`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a local database. In the Windows world you would usually use .sdf file. This is a good tutorial to get you started.
[Local Database Tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7d3362/use-local-database-file-in-window-application-C-Sharp/)

Also you can see how to deploy it here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: is this local database `.sdf file` works with `c#` or `c++ Qt` or `both` ?

Comment: Works with c# for sure. Not sure about QT as I have never worked with it.

Comment: Not sure from your question but did you still need to access the database or is it just for the client computer? If just for the client computer the .sdf will work fine. If you still need access to the data after the client installs it you might want to look at a hosted instance of SQL server that allows remote connections.

Comment: Is `SQL Server Compact` the same as `local database .sdf file` does not require install a database server  ?.

Comment: Yes the .sdf file runs on SQL Server Compact. Take a look at the MSDN link I posted. When the user installs your application it will automatically install SQL Server Compact (if the user doesn't have it already).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `+1 for you` , I want to give you the best answer, but there is another one also has a good answer Mr:`Nejat`.